# iTextSharp convert to .pdf - change MIME Type

Tags: itext, mime-types

**Resolved:**
This had nothing to do with iTextSharp. The culprit is XMPIE and how it renders pdfs.

---

I'm using iTextSharp to convert .pngs to pdfs.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
 var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageBytes);
 document.Add(image);
```

My question is: does this actually convert the .png to a .pdf? Does it change the Mime type?

I am trying to use the converted image in XMPIE, which does not support .pngs. The "conversion" seems to work -- meaning that I get a pdf that has my image on it. But when I try to display that image in xmpie it displays all blurred out and grey. The "conversion" works with .jpegs but not .pngs.

Is there another way to convert an image (.png) to a .pdf. My code just seems to add the image to the .pdf and doesn't actually change the mime type.

Comment: If the pdf looks good in Acrobat, blame xmpie. Does it look good in Acrobat?

Comment: Mime type is metadata, and is not encoded inside the bytes of a file. Converting one file format to another, and one mime type to another, are two separate operations.

Comment: Thanks, @AmedeeVanGasse, I will look into converting the mime type then.

Comment: @PauloSoares, yep it looks perfect in Acrobat.

Comment: Blurred and grey leads me to suspect that the png has transparency in it and xmpie doesn't deal with pdfs with transparency. If the image looks good in Acrobat you'll have to question xmpie about the problem and not iText.

Comment: @PauloSoares, there was no transparency